# How to replace some character in a string with a single character of type char?

Tags: java, string, replace, char

As an example I have `abcdbab` and I want to replace all `ab` with `A`.

The output is `AcdbA`.

I try this one but it gives an error.

```
char N = 65;
String S = "abcdbab";
S = S.replaceAll("ab", N);
System.out.print(S);
```

Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also change

```
S = S.replaceAll("ab", N);
```

to

```
S = S.replaceAll("ab", "" + N);
```

referencing here, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm replaceAll takes a String, String not String, Char

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method `String#replace(CharSequence, char)`, you will need to find the one that is closes to your needs and adjust to it, for example, there is a `String#replaceAll(CharSequence, CharSequence)` method and `char` can be represented as a `CharSequence` (or a `String`), for example...

```
S = S.replaceAll("ab", Character.toString(N));
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) (remember `String` is immutable, so either use the result or assign it back) like

```
String str = "abcdbab";
System.out.println(str);
str = str.replace("ab", "A");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is

```
abcdbab
AcdbA
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the following line:

```
char N = 65;
```

to

```
String N = "A";
```

and it'll work fine.